# Acessing elements of an array from another class

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
int x;
const int Maxword = 5;
char Guess[Maxword] {};
std::string words[Maxword] = {
    "Hello",
    "World",
    "Shift",
    "Green",
    "Seven"
};
srand(time(NULL));
int iSecret = rand() % Maxword;
std::string Word(words[iSecret]);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    std::cout << Word[i] << std::endl;

}
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    std::cout << ("Please enter the letters you would like to guess") << std::endl;
    std::cin >> Guess[i];
    std::cout << Guess[i] << std::endl;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (Guess[i] == Word[i]) {
        std::cout << Guess[i] << "\t" << "Is in the right place" << std::endl;
    } else if (Guess[i] != Word[i]) {
        std::cout << Guess[i] << "\t" << "Isnt in the right place" << std::endl;
    } else {

    }

}
void InTheWord() {
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

}
}
```

I want to use elements of arrays Guess[] and Word[] how would I access them from the other function. So like I want to check if a letter from Guess[] is in the array of Word[] so id have to pass down each letter and check guess against every letter in word then return to the other function to then print out whether the letter that the person guessed was in the word that the program generated.

Comment: Pass them as argument `void InTheWord(char (&guesses)[5], std::string (&words)[5])`. (syntax would be simpler by using `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of C-arrays).

Comment: First answer: Why do you want to use a function? What is the purpose?

Comment: For my project have to use a number of functions so just need to make some even if they arent needed

Comment: Is there not a way I can refer to a certain number using a variable like i like ive done in the previous function